# Is there a way to make a subclass not respond to a method that its superclass implements, and have the compiler throw an error?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Suppose I have a class called 'Node' that has a method 'addChild'

```
@interface Node : NSObject

-(void) addChild:(Node *)n;
```

and I have a subclass called 'Sprite' that **shouldn't** respond to this method.

```
@interface Sprite : Node
```

I know I could do something like this:

```
@implementation Sprite

-(void) addChild:(Node *)n {
    NSLog(@"Don't call addChild on a Sprite!");
}
```

or

```
-(void) addChild:(Node *)n {
    NSAssert(NO, @"Don't call addChild on a Sprite!");
}
```

But is there a way to declare that the subclass doesn't respond to this method, and have the compiler throw an error? Getting a compiler error would be a lot better than a runtime error in this case.

**EDIT**

I realize this violates the Liskov substitution principle. But in Apple's documentation there's this:

"Any doesNotRecognizeSelector: messages are generally sent only by the runtime system.     However, they can be used in program code to prevent a method from being inherited. For example, an NSObject subclass might renounce the copy or init method by re-implementing it to include a doesNotRecognizeSelector: message..."

I don't understand why throwing a runtime error rather than a compile-time error would be any less in violation of this principle.

Comment: That is a violation of the ["Liskov substitution principle"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), don't do that.

Comment: You can write your code anyway you like. The thing is that right now it seems like a good idea, but will it still be a good idea to ignore well know principles next year when the code is being extended? Will someone, perhaps you, be surprised that this class can not be used inlace of it's super class? OK, all in all what you are proposing is not nearly as bad as a lot of code I see--not that that is a free pass. :-)

Comment: Hey, no, don't get me wrong; I'm a huge fan of correct, what-you-expect-it-to-be code. But I'm also a fan of simple, and to my mind  having a @iwontrespondto in the header file would be a pretty logical way to do this. It would a lot better than having a doesNotRecognizeSelector: buried in the implementation file at least. But it's looking like that just doesn't fit the established design patterns, so I guess that's not the way to do it. Having an abstract class that both Node and Sprite inherit from still seems overly complicated and harder to understand to me. But oh well.

Answer (score 4):

No.

There is a principle in OOP called the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which states that you must always be able to substitute an instance of a subclass for an instance of the original class without altering the desired behaviour of the program in question.  In your case, you desire that Nodes should respond to `addChild:`; in order to obey the LSP we must have Sprites respond to `addChild:` too.

That's not to say that there's nothing you can do.  You could have Sprites throw an exception when you send `addChild:` to them, or have them silently ignore it, but I think that what you actually want is for Node and Sprite to be different subclasses of the same parent - let's call it AbstractNode.  You'd move most of the logic from Node into AbstractNode, then just implement `addChild:` on Node.

Comment: This makes sense, but I feel like since Sprite inherits 99% of Node (everything except for that particular method), creating an abstract class that they both inherit from just seems like over engineering. In Apple's documentation they describe doesNotRecognizeSelector: with "...can be used in program code to prevent a method from being inherited."

If there's a mechanism for preventing a method from being inherited, that that violates this principle already. Having a compiler error rather than a run time error doesn't change that.

Comment: Is it overengineering for your object model to match the behaviour of your objects?  Perhaps.  Should they provide a way of doing what you want to do?  Perhaps.  But your question was "is there a way to..", and the answer, for now, is no.

Comment: I interpreted your answer as "Don't do that because it violates this principle" rather than "No there's no way to do that. Also there's this principle that says it's a bad design paradigm anyway". And if that's the case and there's no way to actually do this, then I suppose that is the right answer.

Comment: Yeah. I included the principle bit because I think that it's why they haven't given us a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a compile time error, but during runtime you can try:

```
-(void)myMethod {
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
}
```

However, I think you need to refactor these classes where you want to effectively eliminate a method from the parent class.  It seems that you're violating inheritance otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a category to extend the class and implement your addChild method in that category.

```
@interface Node(firstCategory)
-(void)addChild:(Node *)n;
@end

@implementation Node(firstCategory)
// your implementation of addChild
@end
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to have it respond to the super class (In this case 'Node'). Just not implement it on your subclass 'Sprite' or manually call it inside your method. If your want to do something extra.

```
@implementation Sprite

-(void) addChild:(Node *)n {
    [super addChild:n];
    // Do some other stuff 
}
```

If your want your subclass to ignore the method completely you have to implement the method and do nothing, but if this is the case you've misunderstood the inheritance paradigm.

@implementation Sprite

```
-(void) addChild:(Node *)n {
     // Ignore the method
}
```

Comment: @downvoter - Really? Mike clearly want to violate the LSP which means he misunderstood the subclassing (inheritance paradigm). Please tell me why you've down voted my answer?